# How to skip while() loop's condition when object has not yet been initialized?

Tags: java, while-loop, initialization

I'm getting NullPointerException because I try to check some value from an object that has yet to be initialized and value is still `null` value. The reason for this is that I'm waiting to initialize object only when necessary, when is not necessary I figure I don't need to waste more memory space.

I'm getting this exception because `player2.getHandTotal()` has not been initialized yet so there is no method to pull value from. Now, how should I formulate my while loop to not throw this exception when I check for a value? I tried to throw `(player2 != null && dealer.getHandTotal() <= player2.getHandTotal())` and hoped to short circuit checking it but that doesn't work...

The `player2` meant to be a hand which will be used when cards are `split` into 2 hands for the same player. If there are no requirements for `split` such as no 2 cards or cards ranks are not the same then I don't need `player2` object to be initialized.

**I really don't want to double my code! The reason for this is that I would have to double A LOT of code!** And I would be better off initializing `player2` object even when not necessary!

How to fix this?

```
while(dealer.getHandTotal() <= 15 && 
        (dealer.getHandTotal() <= player.getHandTotal() || 
        dealer.getHandTotal() <= player2.getHandTotal()))
{
    deck = drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);
}
```

Comment: Define a proper strategy for initializing your objects. "Only when necessary" in this case seems more like "without any specific plan, really".

Comment: If the player has not been initialized, he is probably not sitting at the table yet, and the dealer is probably busy counting his cards and player1 drinking a scotch. So you should wait I think...

Comment: It depends on your logic. You can try this one: `dealer != null && player != null && player2 != null && (dealer.getHandTotal() <= 15 && (dealer.getHAndTotal() <= player.getHandTotal() || dealer.getHAndTotal() <= player2.getHandTotal())`. This will fix your NPE, but maybe it is not doing what you want. I suggest always initialize player1 and player2!

Comment: also if `(player2 != null &&...` doesn't solve your problem, than `dealer` or `player` are null.

Comment: @Jon, `player2` meant to be a hand which will be used when cards are split into 2 hands for the same player. If there are no requirements for `split` such as no 2 cards or cards ranks are not the same then I don't need `player2` object to be initialized.

Comment: Whats the problem with putting a Null check before the while loop as zip suggests?

Comment: @maloney, I have more code that also depends on this type of thing such as `if((player.getHandTotal() < dealer.getHandTotal() && dealer.getHandTotal() <= BLACKJACK) || (player2.getHandTotal() < dealer.getHandTotal() && dealer.getHandTotal() <= BLACKJACK)) {}`. I would have to double multiple if statements too.

Comment: @zip, but I'm just trying to save some memory.

Comment: Are the checks always the same? If so you could put it into a boolean method and if true then continue...?

Comment: @maloney, I always check for player and player's split hand when using split, hit, and sand (if talking about blackjack game) and when possible do 2 things at once, for example hit must be performed on both player and split hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The player2 meant to be a hand which will be used when cards are split
>   into 2 hands for the same player. If there are no requirements for
>   split such as no 2 cards or cards ranks are not the same then I don't
>   need player2 object to be initialized.

So your class structure is not correct: a Player (and the Dealer) should have one or more Hands and the condition should something like:

```
while(dealer.getHand().getTotal() <= 15 && 
        dealer.getHand().getTotal() <= getMaximumHandTotal()) {
   ...
}

private int getMaximumHandTotal() {
   int max = -1;
   for(Hand hand : player.getHands()) {
      if(hand.getTotal() > max) { max = hand.getTotal(); }
   }
   return max;
}
```

Then in the future when you want to add extra players you just need to add an extra loop in the getMaximumHandTotal() over all the players.

Answer (score 1):

The added condition *player2 != null* should work. Is there something else that is throwing the NullPointerException? Can you show us the stack trace after you've made the following change?

```
while (dealer.getHandTotal() <= 15 && 
        (dealer.getHandTotal() <= player.getHandTotal() || 
        (player2 != null && dealer.getHandTotal() <= player2.getHandTotal())))
{
    deck = drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check all the values if it is null or not even before entering into loop? say like this `if(object1 != null && object2 !=null )` or if it is primitive type if(value == -1 || value == 0)`. So before you enter loop you have validations for all values

Comment: Then I would have to have 2 separate while loops, though.

Comment: No 2 while loops, like this if(..validations of all variables.. ) { while () }

Comment: If you use only one loop that contains player2 and checks if it's null at the start, it won't run the loop without player2 (even though it has to be run without player2 as well). Use 2 while loops if you want to do this.

Comment: The problem is that the answer to my program depends on this answer because if I can't do this in one loop, I would have to double a lot of other code comparing to modifying 1 line of code to just initialize not always necessary object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `player2.getHandTotal` in your condition statement when you're not certain it won't be null.

When player2 is null, it means that the first condition is met but it also means that the 2nd condition will throw a `NullPointerException` because you use that same reference there with a method.

I'd suggest checking some values whether or not they're null before entering the while loop.

Comment: I'm certain that it WILL be null most of the time. But will not be null low percentage of the time.

Comment: You might want to split it up in two while loops, depending whether or not there is a player 2 and choose the appropriate action from there.

Comment: I'd like to know if I could do this in 1 loop.

Comment: Jeroen: What you say is not completely correct. For example in `if( object != null && object.toString().equals("Blah") )` if object is null the first expression becomes false and thus the whole expression, no matter what the second one will be. Therefore the second one will never be actually executed. But for this to work, the nullcheck has to be the first expression in the "&&".

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't want to waste memory space, but I do not know if that is possible. Probably it is, but I would prefer to catch the NullPointerException with a try-catch block around your loop, or inside it.

```
try{
  while(dealer.getHandTotal() <= 15 && 
        (dealer.getHandTotal() <= player.getHandTotal() || 
        dealer.getHandTotal() <= player2.getHandTotal()))
  {
    deck = drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);
  }

} catch (NullPointerException npe){
  // do something
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Any possibility of doing this in 1 loop?

Comment: Catching a NPE may be dodgy as it may stop showing you a real problem with your code. I would avoid it if possible

Comment: Not mentioning much more costly than simple if-statement.